# Why am I getting this error --> Operation `users.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms when i host my app online

Tags: node.js, mongoose, passport.js, mongodb-atlas

This is the error I am getting while registering using passport in the mongodb atlas after having hosted my project in heroku.
[image]

But when I try to do it locally from my system, everything works fine.
I am enclosing pics of the relevant codes [image: My code]

Comment: Make sure you're actually connecting to the database before attempting to access it.

Comment: Please post your code directly to question, no need of adding extra URLs that can become invalid in future.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy to fix.

basically, you need to go to the mongo website, then you go to the Network Access tab and add a new IP that is `0.0.0.0/0`

Now Heroku can access your DB

Hope you found it helpful! :)